# Get coordinates from a contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

## Background

From [the documentation example here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html), one can easily produce the following contour plot with the code snippet.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

# Create a simple contour plot with labels using default colors.  The
# inline argument to clabel will control whether the labels are draw
# over the line segments of the contour, removing the lines beneath
# the label
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
```

[image]

## My Goal

I have obtained my contour plot and meanwhile got the `matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet` instance `CS`. In the example snippet, `CS` is only used for `clabel()`. However for my case, **I need to obtain either the equation of the contour line or the coordinate set for further computation.**

**How can I extract the coordinates of the contour line from the instance `CS`? OR
How can I achieve it in other ways?**

I bet there must be a way of doing so. Otherwise, the contour thing is only a "vase for visualization" then.

Answer (score 24):

You can get the coordinates of the contours from the `CS.allsegs` list.

Try:

```
dat0= CS.allsegs[0][0]
plt.plot(dat0[:,0],dat0[:,1])
```

to plot the first (-1) contour level.

Comment: What if you have multiple contour levels at the same value, say multiple (-1) contour levels... How can you extract the coordinates of the set of all these values?

Comment: To clarify: What if you have multiple regions at the same contour level value, say multiple (-1) contour regions... How can you extract the coordinates of the set of all these regions?

Comment: All the individual contour lines are placed in the 2d array (CS.allsegs). If you check this array, you will find the lines corresponding to the same contour value placed at the same first index.