# Determine outer contour of boolean function

Tags: python, contour

I would like to determine the contour of a boolean function defined over two variables, each in the 0, 1 range.  I do not have access to the explicit form of the function: it is a black box that returns a boolean for each pairs of variables, so I don't know how to convert it to a continuous function and use the first answer below.  The region is convex, and it may reach the edges of the ranges of the parameters.  Language is python.  The function may be expensive to calculate, so the brute force grid approach I have below is slow in addition to being inaccurate.  How can I improve things?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y): return ((x-0.3)**2+(y-0.4)**2 <= 0.1) # Example of function; may extend outside region.  In reality, form is not known.

xs, ys = np.linspace(0, 1, 11), np.linspace(0, 1, 11) # Brute force grid
for x in xs:
    for y in ys:  plt.plot(x, y, 'ro' if f(x, y) else 'b+')

cntr = [] # List of unique, approximate contour points
for x in xs:
    col = [y for y in ys if f(x, y)]
    if (col != []) and (not ((x, min(col)) in cntr)): cntr.append((x, min(col))) 
    if (col != []) and (not ((x, max(col)) in cntr)): cntr.append((x, max(col))) 
for y in ys:
    row = [x for x in xs if f(x, y)]
    if (row != []) and (not ((min(row), y) in cntr)): cntr.append((min(row), y)) 
    if (row != []) and (not ((max(row), y) in cntr)): cntr.append((max(row), y)) 

plt.plot(np.transpose(cntr)[0], np.transpose(cntr)[1], 'kv') # Contour in black
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: illustration of effect of level on @Arne's answer:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is always going to be somewhat approximate, because you can't sample every point, but there are two functions that can help to simplify the code and speed things up: [`np.meshgrid()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy.meshgrid) and [`plt.contour()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html). The latter allows specifying the `levels` you want to plot, so you can define a real-valued function by leaving the threshold out of your Boolean function, and pass the threshold as the level to plot to `plt.contour()` instead:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f_continuous(x, y): 
    return (x - 0.3)**2 + (y - 0.4)**2  # real-valued instead of Boolean;
    # define the 0.1 threshold in the contour plot function instead
    
xs, ys = np.linspace(0, 1, 11), np.linspace(0, 1, 11) # Brute force grid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

plt.contour(X, Y, f_continuous(X, Y), levels=[0.1])
plt.show()
```

[image: Contour Plot]

**Edit: What if the function is a black box and can't be turned into a continuous one?**

You can still use `plt.contour()`, by passing a value between the Boolean values 0 and 1 as the contour level. The interpolation just doesn't turn out as smooth in this case:

```py
plt.contour(X, Y, f(X, Y), levels=[0.5])
plt.show()
```

[image: Boolean Contour Plot]

As the answer you linked to notes, you can get the coordinates of the calculated points on the contour line by catching the `QuadContourSet` object returned by `plt.contour()` and accessing its `allsegs` attribute:

```py
contour = plt.contour(X, Y, f(X, Y), levels=[0.5])
contour.allsegs
```

```
[[array([[0.  , 0.25],
         [0.05, 0.2 ],
         [0.1 , 0.15],
         ...
         [0.1 , 0.65],
         [0.05, 0.6 ],
         [0.  , 0.55]])]]
```

Comment: Adding the information on how to extract the points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418901/get-coordinates-from-the-contour-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks - this works nicely for the minimal reproducible example I provided, and is a lot faster than my method.  However, in practice, I don't know the form of the function (it's what I want to determine from the plot), so I don't know how to transform the discrete values to continuous ones.  Have edited question.

Comment: The edit is very useful.  Note that by setting a level closer to 1 (eg 0.99), you get closer to the discrete points, which may or may not be desired.